# ui-calendar events not working

Tags: jquery, angularjs, calendar, fullcalendar, angular-ui-bootstrap

I just integrated Angularjs ui-calendar in my project. It seems to be working except one thing, events. I was trying to put my custom logic on user click event but somehow that's not working.

I have followed [this](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-calendar#options) and [this](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-calendar/). But somehow, following events are not working:

```
dayClick
eventDrop
eventResize
```

Any ideas what can be the possible reason? I have simply copy pasted the entire code, so there is no chance of mistake. I have verified that it is not working ny putting some console messages just to see if events are getting triggered. But there are no messages printed on event click on console.

Thanks

Based on the answer, sharing my updated code:

```js
     /* alert on eventClick */
    $scope.alertOnEventClick = function(date, jsEvent, view) {
      alert(date.title + ' was clicked ');
      console.log(date);
    };
    /* alert on Drop */
    $scope.alertOnDrop = function(event, delta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view) {
      alert('Event Droped to make dayDelta ' + delta);
      console.log("date");
    };
    /* alert on Resize */
    $scope.alertOnResize = function(event, delta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view) {
      alert('Event Resized to make dayDelta ' + delta);
      console.log("date");
    };

    /* Change View */
    $scope.changeView = function(view, calendar) {
      uiCalendarConfig.calendars[calendar].fullCalendar('changeView', view);
    };
    /* Render Tooltip */
    $scope.eventRender = function(event, element, view) {
      element.attr({
        'tooltip': event.title,
        'tooltip-append-to-body': true
      });
      $compile(element)($scope);
    };

    $scope.events = [{
      title: 'All Day Event',
      start: new Date(y, m, 1)
    }, {
      title: 'Long Event',
      start: new Date(y, m, d - 5),
      end: new Date(y, m, d - 2)
    }, {
      id: 999,
      title: 'Repeating Event',
      start: new Date(y, m, d - 3, 16, 0),
      allDay: false
    }, {
      id: 999,
      title: 'Repeating Event',
      start: new Date(y, m, d + 4, 16, 0),
      allDay: false
    }, {
      title: 'Birthday Party',
      start: new Date(y, m, d + 1, 19, 0),
      end: new Date(y, m, d + 1, 22, 30),
      allDay: false
    }, {
      title: 'Click for Google',
      start: new Date(y, m, 28),
      end: new Date(y, m, 29),
      url: 'http://google.com/'
    }];

    $scope.uiConfig = {
      calendar: {
        height: 600,
        editable: true,
        header: {
          left: 'month agendaWeek agendaDay',
          center: 'title',
          right: 'today prev,next'
        },
        eventClick: $scope.alertOnEventClick,
        eventDrop: $scope.alertOnDrop,
        eventResize: $scope.alertOnResize,
        eventRender: $scope.eventRender
      }
    };

    $scope.eventSources = [$scope.events];
```

Answer (score 1):

Are the others events working? The code in your [first link](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-calendar#options) is incomplete.
I've created a [plunker where you can reproduce a basic example from the second link](http://plnkr.co/edit/kuFjhi?p=preview). 
Basically, what you can do is:

a) Create a function when you define the event:

```
eventResize: function(){
          alert("event resize");
        },
```

b) Make a reference to that function:

```
$scope.uiConfig = {
    eventDrop: $scope.alertOnDrop, 
    (...)
};

$scope.alertOnDrop = function(){
    alert("event drop");
}
```

I've created a [new plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/lvBobt?p=preview) reproducing your snippet. Just define your functions before you reference them in the Config and it will work.

### About the tooltip

I think is hard to work with Angular-ui due to all its dependencies that becomes usually out of date. You can follow an [open issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-calendar/issues/266) about its special dependency on some angular versions.

The same happens with the tooltip. The tooltip is managed by the twitter bootstrap.css, but it's not working out of the box with the latest angular-ui demo code. With `twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap.css` at least works ok.

I did [another plunker xD](http://plnkr.co/edit/LbVkCo?p=preview) where you can check the tooltip working properly. Then you should compare all your dependencies and its versions. I've also comment this situation in an [open issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-calendar/issues/102#issuecomment-128130807) at the angular-ui project.

Comment: I have updated my code. I have used exactly same code but still it is not working. Can you please tale a look at it and let me know what you think can be possible issue ?

Comment: I've extend my answer. Check the new plunkr I've made with your code.

Comment: Yeah, it is working now except eventRender: $scope.eventRender. Any specific reason why eventRender doesn't work ? I have updated my code based on your answer. Really appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: Ey, this is scalating quickly xD 
I think this is really going out of the scope of your first question because now is not related with events but with styles... Anyway I did another (3 and counting...) plunker and extended my answer to explain that situation.